# Google Analytics - Pagehits from Paloalto, Coral Springs, Ashburn

Tags: google-analytics

There are days when I receive a very large number of page hits from areas in Paloalto, Coral Springs, Ashburn. I know these are not real hits because it is geographically incorrect and also totally out of proportion to other days (and happens in bursts of 2-3 hrs)

I am assuming this will be clogging my server and eating my resources.

1. Why or what is the purpose of these page hits ? I understand Ashburn has Amazon data centres - but why Palo alto and Coral Springs. More importantly what purpose do these hits serve?
2. How do I prevent these hits from happening since they probably are eating my resources.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The city names are not helpful. If you have IP addresses/ranges, then that will tell us/you a lot more. Can you post some example IP addresses for each city in your question?? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks. I understand you have to include some code in GA to get the IP, but which may in violation of google terms. How does one do this on the server side - getting from the server logs ?

Comment: Yes. You want to look at the server logs. If you do not have a log file analyzer, then I recommend Piwik which is free and absolutely the best. It could be handy if your log file is huge. Otherwise, I have edited huge files before, slow as snot, but okay.

Comment: +1 for the advice on the log file analyser. Thanks, will try it out.